# Make timer for game to run for 2min

Tags: c++, timer

I'm trying to make a game using C++ (in Visual Studio 2015).
I want to make the game run for X minutes and then end.
I have a function `play()` that calls all other functions required and I need to make `play()` run for 2min. 
I've tried putting `play()` in loops that run for some time, but none of them work. I am not able to find any other question that addresses the problem I'm facing and so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us what's in `play()` and how it is called?

Comment: It's also helpful, when describing attempts that didn't work, to specify *in what particular way* they didn't work. Compiler errors, never stopping the game at all, stopping the game too early / too late, re-starting the game instead of stopping it, preventing the game from running normally, crashing the game/computer, catching fire... all of these are possible failure modes, and each one tells a different story about what might be going wrong. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you record the time once at the start of your game:

```
time_t startTimeSeconds = time(NULL); // must include 'ctime'
```

Every update (game loop iteration) you can check to see if the elapsed time has exceeded two minutes:

```
if (time(NULL) - startTimeSeconds >= 120) // two minutes
    stopGame();
```

Comment: In case the `time` function does not give enough precision, consider using `QueryPerformanceCounter`. Follow [this link](http://www.songho.ca/misc/timer/timer.html) for a nice example.

Answer (score 0):

Your `play()` function not necessary should not be executed in the loop. Instead, you can use this function, to loop your game. Here is some minimal example, how you can use it:

```
#include <chrono>

void play()
{
    // record the time, as soon you entered the function
    auto startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now(); 

    while(!isGameOver())
    {
        // here you can paste your time consuming game logic
        //  i.e. function calls

        auto endTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        // check, if two minutes are over
        if (endTime - startTime > std::chrono::minutes(2))
            gameOver(); /* in this function paste your 'end of the game'-logic */ 
    }
}
```

The main advantage in using `std::chrono` instead of `ctime` is that your time-checking calls are less cryptic, therefore better understandable, especially in initialization part.

Compare `auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::now()` and `time_t startTimeSeconds = time(NULL);`